# Is this UML class diagram close to the specification described

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Is the design of this UML correct based on the specification below. Also I am extremely sorry that the UML is hand written because I could not install IMB RSA on my pc and could not find a suitable substitute.

Here is the spec

```
Consider a new mobile app (BuzApp) to be developed by Tyler Hill
University to help its community and visitors to identify the most
convenient bus stop. The University has several bus stops dispersed on
a wide geographical area, which are served by several bus routes. The
purpose of the app is to help the University community members
(students and staff) and visitors to find the most convenient bus stop to
reach their final destinations. Based on the routes and positions of the
buses, and on the position of the app user, the app should be able to
localise the best bus stop based on: the time it takes for a bus to arrive
at a particular bus stop, and the time it takes a user to reach that same
bus stop. The average walking speed is fixed for visitors, but for the
community members is calculated based on historical data.

The app will rely on bus companies for providing the bus routes, the
positions of its buses, and the time it takes for a bus to reach a
particular bus stop, together with the information whether a particular
bus is full or not. The app will rely on the University Campus Services
for providing the maps, the pedestrian paths, which include short cuts
that are only available to community members depending on their
University status that is captured by their personal card number
(HillOne).
```

If you could let me know how I can improve it that would be great. I find it very difficult to create UML class diagrams by reading specifications, any pointers on the best way to read the specification and transform to a UML would be greatly appreicated. [image]

Comment: Diagram is hard to read. Quick tip: Download a free eval of MagicDraw. It installs in seconds and runs on Windows, OS X, and Linux.

Comment: @JimL. okay I will do that now and repost

Comment: In the meantime, I can read enough to give you some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that your design does not seem correct. You are missing the problem domain altogether.

Rather than dive straight into designing some solution, you should model the problem domain described in the text provided to you. For example, where are the concepts `Bus Stop`, `Geographical Area`, `Bus Route`, `Location`, `Bus`, `Traversal Duration`, `Map`, `Student Id Card`? Where are the associations between them? What are the association-end multiplicities and names? What non-technical behaviors naturally make sense in each class? Ignoring the problem domain is perilous, as I recently explained in [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173654/how-to-model-classes-that-do-calculations-and-store-them/37176518#37176518).

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to do it in timed situation because a question like this will come up in my exam and i will have about 10 minutes to draw the UML class diagram.